Angular 17 app freezes on new route network request
My Angular app freezes when I navigate to a new route and if the new route has an asynchronous request.
It doesn't affect all my routes and doesn't happen in the past. Just started happening after my update to the latest version.
I have unsubscribed from all possible subscriptions.
I noticed that when I switched from using chart.js to ngx-chartjs. One of my routes that freezes in the past started working. I did the same for my moment.js library hoping it would fix it because those are the two third party libraries I have installed, but still same result.
Please is anybody facing a similar app freeze on route change using angular 17?

Impossible to help without more context, please give some code exemple. Maybe you are an infinite loop somewhere. Or function that compute a lot call in the template ??

Thanks, Tim.
Let me check if I can provide more details.

I figured it out while trying to send the code.
I used a lot of duplicate async pipes in the HTML template, so I handled subscriptions in a neater approach by utilizing the combineLatest RXJS operator. Then I handled the subscription in my ts file once.

I figured it out while trying to send the code.
I used a lot of duplicate async pipes in the HTML template, so I handled subscriptions in a neater approach by utilizing the combineLatest RXJS operator. Then I handled the subscription in my ts file once.
